# How to read array data from the firestore using kotlin?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in android development and when I read array data from firestore using following code

```
val variable = arrayOf(document.get("restaurant"))
```

and then loop over the variable using code

```
varibale.forEach {
    Log.d("someTag", ${it.toString()} + " is your data")
}
```

I get the result with square brackets at log as following
*[somedata, somedata2] is your data*

my problem is that *forEach* loop runs only once and I am not able to get the result (without square brackets) as following

*somedata is your data*
*somedata2 is your data*

I have 2 elements in my restaurant array in firestore
I will be very thankfull to any one who will help me.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually wrapping an array/list into another array when using `arrayOf`, that's why you see those brackets. Instead, try casting your `document.get("restaurant")` and then looping directly through it.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.. some more info document.get("restaurant") was a ArrayList so I have to cast into ArrayList as follows
  "val variable = document.get("restaurant") as ArrayList<String>"

Answer (score 0):

`arrayOf` doesn't parse an array.  It creates a new array using the elements you pass to it.  That's not what you want.  You should instead cast `document.get("restaurant")` to the type that you expect to get from Firestore.

If a field is an array of strings, then the SDK will give you a `List<*>`, and you will need to make sure each item in the list is a String, if that's what you stored in the array.

```
val variable = document.get("restaurant") as List<*>
// Iterate variable here, make sure to check or convert items to strings
```